# Android pubnub chat using parse giving incorrect authentication key error

Tags: android, parse-platform, chat, pubnub

I am working on an android application. In my app I have to implement pubnub chat with parse.com. I found the following code.
[github link](https://github.com/WizTheEngineer/DroidMessenger)

Successfully integrated project in Android studio.After login , when I started chat message is not senting and I am getting

`Error sending message:[Error: 112-0] : Authentication Failure. Incorrect Authentication Key`.

If we login again , then I can see all the messages I sent but can't sent new messages.Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Hi!  Your API Key must have `PAM` enabled.  You need to modify this library to include an `auth_key` by `pubnub.setAuthKey("my_auth_key");` near here: https://github.com/WizTheEngineer/DroidMessenger/blob/6f95a6f08bdec775b60cb6a0cffd9b72889cbf59/app/src/main/java/com/waynebjackson/androidmessaging/MessagingApp.java#L53  Also your parse server code needs to `pubnub.grant({...})` permission and create an `auth_key` for your android client to use.

Answer (score 1):

## PubNub Access Manager

As indicated by the comments, if you enable Access Manager on your key (which is now **FREE** for all account types), you must grant read and/or write access to channels on an auth_key that your server generates. See [PubNub Access Manager tutorial for more details](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/pam-security).

If you are not ready to implement this server side *grant* logic yet, then disable Access Manager on your key until you are ready to implement the required grant behavior on your server.

Once you have the basic functionality implemented, we highly recommend that you do implement Access Manager features into your application so that you can control who has access to which channels and what sort of access: read, write or manage. PubNub provides all the necessary checks when PubNub operations attempted but the PubNub client code.

## PubNub Parse SDK

For details about using PubNub with Parse, we have a [Parse SDK](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/parse-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk) for that.